# set few selected words to lowercase in a string that has been capitalized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for the solution of this problem for some time. I have a sentence in paragraph tag and a class that turns the text in this tag to capitalize, i want that only few words to remain in lowercase and rest to stay in capitalized format

```
<p class="words">this Is A Text That needs To Be Formatted</p>

<!--css-->

.words{text-transform:capitalize}
```

all i want is the words like "is" "a" "to" to remain in lowercase format and rest in title case using jquery or javascript, keeping in mind that the text is by default written in title case, for e.g like this

```
<p class="words">This is a Text That Needs to Be Formatted</p>
```

Comment: I think the term for this kind of text is TitleCase.

Comment: yes, i was giving the CSS reference here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap those with a `span` tag with a custom style(or use a common class) to convert lowercase.

```js
// use html() method with a callback to iterate over if there is multiple
// then replace needed words with a wrapped span element

$('p.words').html((_, html) => html.replace(/\b(?:is|a|to)\b/ig, '<span style="text-transform:lowercase">$&</span>'))
```

```css
.words {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="words">this Is A Text That needs To Be Formatted</p>
```

With common class:

```js
// use html() method with a callback to iterate over if there is multiple
// then replace needed words with a wrapped span element

$('p.words').html((_, html) => html.replace(/\b(?:is|a|to)\b/ig, '<span class="lower">$&</span>'))
```

```css
.words {
  text-transform: capitalize
}

.lower{
  text-transform: lowercase
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="words">this Is A Text That needs To Be Formatted</p>
```

---

Or in case you are not using `text-transform` style to `.words` then simply replace with lowercase itself.

```js
// use html() method with a callback to iterate over if there is multiple
// then replace needed words with a wrapped span element

$('p.words').html((_, html) => html.replace(/\b(?:is|a|to)\b/ig, m=>m.toLowerCase()))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="words">this Is A Text That needs To Be Formatted</p>
```

---

***FYI :*** *Updating HTML content using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method will recreate all the DOM elements inside the tag so any attached event handler for the nested element will no longer work.*

Comment: Thanks, but what if the text is already written in title case for few words, like i have updated my question again for more clarity

Comment: i am implementing the same thing that you have mentioned @pranav C Balan but it does not seems to be working

Comment: no need now friend , this works now, thanks a lot @pranav C Balan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190989/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-daljeet-dhaliwal).

Answer (score 1):

Use span:

```html
<p class="words">This <span class="lowercase">Is</span> A Text That Needs <span class="lowercase">To>/span> Be Formatted</p>
```

I don't think there is another solution using only html/css

Comment: Well thanks, but i was thinking to sort this out using javascript or jquery